# QWebEngineView Settings

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have a code here:

```
QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
self.setUrl(QUrl("https://google.com"))
```

**"self"** is QWebEngineView(new class) and nope it does not work. Can you help? I searched a lot...

P.S. It has no errors.

Comment: show complete code.

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work? that description can have multiple interpretations.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r5bvVdsx
Here is a simple example of my code. Websites say flash is not installed or enabled

Comment: That you have to indicate in your question, we are not fortune-tellers, read [ask]

Comment: I've tried it in PyQt 5.9 and it works correctly: https://imgur.com/a/vlOjj

Comment: Um. QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled is for flash plugin, if you test it, it does not work. So who reads this he may know what is that setting for...

Comment: Flash is no longer workable, that technology is from the past, I do not think Google is currently using it due to the serious security problems it had.

Comment: I have executed the code that you have provided in the link and that is the result I get.

Comment: Are you sure? because Facebook apps use flash, Flash games need Flash... Google Chrome currently supports flash. My goal is not just google.com :D I need Flash player support doesn't matter if its unsecure for today